# Return back to location on page after Post request using PHP LARAVEL

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, post

I am trying to build a one page web page using PHP laravel and all its features.

I use javascript to scroll through the pages when pressing specific links.

At the bottom of the page I have a form that runs some php code (sends an email,...)
After this POST request I redirect back to my webpage.

The problem is that when I redirect back I see the top of the page and the contact form and error or success codes are at the bottom of my page near the FORM.

This is why I am looking for a way to automatically scroll/move to the contact form after the post request just like i do when pressing the link button.

HTML:

```
        @if (count($errors) > 0)
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
                <ul>
                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                @endforeach
                </ul>
            </div>
        @endif
        @if ($message = Session::get('success'))
            <div class="alert alert-success alert-block">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
            </div>
        @endif
        <form method="post" action="sendemail">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="exampleFormControlInput1">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Email</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="exampleFormControlInput1">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Message</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" name="message" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="8"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" name="send" class="btn btn-secondary" value="Send" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

PHP Route:

```
Route::post('/sendemail', 'App\Http\Controllers\SendEmailController@send');
```

PHP Controller:

```
function send(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
    'name'     =>  'required',
    'email'  =>  'required|email',
    'message' =>  'required'
    ]);

        $data = array(
            'name'      =>  $request->name,
            'email'     =>  $request->email,
            'message'   =>  $request->message
        );
    Mail::to($request->email)->send(new SendMailValidation($data));
    return back()->with('success', 'Thank you!');
}
```

Javascript (atm only used for client side browsing when pressing a link item):

```
let  contactLinkItem = document.querySelector("#contactLinkItem");

contactLink.addEventListener("click", navigateContact, false);

function navigateContact() {
  contactLinkItem.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if errors bag has any messages then call javascript function that you already created above to trigger scrolling behavior

```
@if($errors->any())
  <script>
    navigateContact()
  </script>
@endif


// Your old code
let  contactLinkItem = document.querySelector("#contactLinkItem");

contactLink.addEventListener("click", navigateContact, false);

function navigateContact() {
  contactLinkItem.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
}
```

**Recommendation:**

Use Ajax calls with API to submit your forms (Or Livewire), and you have the ability to show validation errors without scrolling or even leaving the page. This is the best for your users experience.